# Can avplayer play music from mpmusicplayercontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avplayer

is this possible AVPlayer fetch music from ipodlibrary from MPMusicPlayerController and play ,since avplayer cannot access iPodMusicPlayer from MPMusicPlayerController , since AVPlayer support background playing and access to remoteEvents.
The code shown below is from addMusic project. so any help would be appreciated .Thank you

```
void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (
   void                      *inUserData,
   AudioSessionPropertyID    inPropertyID,
   UInt32                    inPropertyValueSize,
   const void                *inPropertyValue
) {

    // ensure that this callback was invoked for a route change
    if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;

    // This callback, being outside the implementation block, needs a reference to the
    //      MainViewController object, which it receives in the inUserData parameter.
    //      You provide this reference when registering this callback (see the call to 
    //      AudioSessionAddPropertyListener).
    MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *) inUserData;

    // if application sound is not playing, there's nothing to do, so return.
    if (controller.appSoundPlayer.playing == 0 ) {

        NSLog (@"Audio route change while application audio is stopped.");
        return;

    } else {

        // Determines the reason for the route change, to ensure that it is not
        //      because of a category change.
        CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = inPropertyValue;

        CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef =
                        CFDictionaryGetValue (
                            routeChangeDictionary,
                            CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason)
                        );

        SInt32 routeChangeReason;

        CFNumberGetValue (
            routeChangeReasonRef,
            kCFNumberSInt32Type,
            &routeChangeReason
        );

        // "Old device unavailable" indicates that a headset was unplugged, or that the
        //  device was removed from a dock connector that supports audio output. This is
        //  the recommended test for when to pause audio.
        if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {

            [controller.appSoundPlayer pause];
            NSLog (@"Output device removed, so application audio was paused.");

            UIAlertView *routeChangeAlertView = 
                    [[UIAlertView alloc]    initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"Playback Paused", @"Title for audio hardware route-changed alert view")
                                                  message: NSLocalizedString (@"Audio output was changed", @"Explanation for route-changed alert view")
                                                 delegate: controller
                                        cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"StopPlaybackAfterRouteChange", @"Stop button title")
                                        otherButtonTitles: NSLocalizedString (@"ResumePlaybackAfterRouteChange", @"Play button title"), nil];
            [routeChangeAlertView show];
            // release takes place in alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method

        } else {

            NSLog (@"A route change occurred that does not require pausing of application audio.");
        }
    }
}



@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize artworkItem;                
@synthesize userMediaItemCollection;    
@synthesize playBarButton;              
@synthesize pauseBarButton;             
@synthesize musicPlayer;                
@synthesize navigationBar;              
@synthesize noArtworkImage;              item has no associated artwork
@synthesize backgroundColorTimer;       

@synthesize nowPlayingLabel;            
@synthesize appSoundButton;             
@synthesize addOrShowMusicButton;       
@synthesize appSoundPlayer;             
@synthesize soundFileURL;               
@synthesize interruptedOnPlayback;      
@synthesize playedMusicOnce;            
@synthesize playing;    

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize artworkItem;                // the now-playing media item's artwork image, displayed in the Navigation bar
@synthesize userMediaItemCollection;    // the media item collection created by the user, using the media item picker   
@synthesize playBarButton;              // the button for invoking Play on the music player
@synthesize pauseBarButton;             // the button for invoking Pause on the music player
@synthesize musicPlayer;                // the music player, which plays media items from the iPod library
@synthesize navigationBar;              // the application's Navigation bar
@synthesize noArtworkImage;             // an image to display when a media item has no associated artwork
@synthesize backgroundColorTimer;       // a timer for changing the background color -- represents an application that is
                                        //      doing something else while iPod music is playing
@synthesize nowPlayingLabel;            // descriptive text shown on the main screen about the now-playing media item
@synthesize appSoundButton;             // the button to invoke playback for the application sound
@synthesize addOrShowMusicButton;       // the button for invoking the media item picker. if the user has already 
                                        //      specified a media item collection, the title changes to "Show Music" and
                                        //      the button invokes a table view that shows the specified collection
@synthesize appSoundPlayer;             // An AVAudioPlayer object for playing application sound
@synthesize soundFileURL;               // The path to the application sound
@synthesize interruptedOnPlayback;      // A flag indicating whether or not the application was interrupted during 
                                        //      application audio playback
@synthesize playedMusicOnce;            // A flag indicating if the user has played iPod library music at least one time
                                        //      since application launch.
@synthesize playing;                    // An application that responds to interruptions must keep track of its playing/
                                        //      not-playing state.

#pragma mark Music control
- (IBAction) AddMusicOrShowMusic: (id) sender {    

    // if the user has already chosen some music, display that list
    if (userMediaItemCollection) {

        MusicTableViewController *controller = [[MusicTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MusicTableView" bundle: nil];
        controller.delegate = self;

        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

        [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
        [controller release];

    } else {

        MPMediaPickerController *picker =
            [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

        picker.delegate                     = self;
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = YES;
        picker.prompt                       = NSLocalizedString (@"Add songs to play", "Prompt in media item picker");


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated: YES];

        [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
        [picker release];
    }
}


- (void) updatePlayerQueueWithMediaCollection: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection {

    // Configure the music player, but only if the user chose at least one song to play
    if (mediaItemCollection) {

        if (userMediaItemCollection == nil) {

            [self setUserMediaItemCollection: mediaItemCollection];
            [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: userMediaItemCollection];
            [self setPlayedMusicOnce: YES];
            [musicPlayer play];


        } else {


            BOOL wasPlaying = NO;
            if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
                wasPlaying = YES;
            }

            MPMediaItem *nowPlayingItem         = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
            NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime  = musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;

            NSMutableArray *combinedMediaItems  = [[userMediaItemCollection items] mutableCopy];
            NSArray *newMediaItems              = [mediaItemCollection items];
            [combinedMediaItems addObjectsFromArray: newMediaItems];

            [self setUserMediaItemCollection: [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems: (NSArray *) combinedMediaItems]];
            [combinedMediaItems release];

            [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: userMediaItemCollection];

            musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem          = nowPlayingItem;
            musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime     = currentPlaybackTime;

            if (wasPlaying) {
                [musicPlayer play];
            }
        }


        navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;

        [addOrShowMusicButton   setTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"Show Music", @"Alternate title for 'Add Music' button, after user has chosen some music")
                                forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}


- (void) restorePlaybackState {

    if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped && userMediaItemCollection) {

        [addOrShowMusicButton   setTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"Show Music", @"Alternate title for 'Add Music' button, after user has chosen some music")
                                forState: UIControlStateNormal];

        if (playedMusicOnce == NO) {

            [self setPlayedMusicOnce: YES];
            [musicPlayer play];
        }
    }

}


#pragma mark Media item picker delegate methods________


- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    [self updatePlayerQueueWithMediaCollection: mediaItemCollection];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated: YES];
}


- (void) mediaPickerDidCancel: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated: YES];
}



#pragma mark Music notification handlers__________________

- (void) handle_NowPlayingItemChanged: (id) notification {

    MPMediaItem *currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];

    UIImage *artworkImage = noArtworkImage;

    MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [currentItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

    // Obtain a UIImage object from the MPMediaItemArtwork object
    if (artwork) {
        artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (30, 30)];
    }

    // Obtain a UIButton object and set its background to the UIImage object
    UIButton *artworkView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [artworkView setBackgroundImage: artworkImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    // Obtain a UIBarButtonItem object and initialize it with the UIButton object
    UIBarButtonItem *newArtworkItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: artworkView];
    [self setArtworkItem: newArtworkItem];
    [newArtworkItem release];

    [artworkItem setEnabled: NO];

    [navigationBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem: artworkItem animated: YES];

    [nowPlayingLabel setText: [
            NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@ %@",
            NSLocalizedString (@"Now Playing:", @"Label for introducing the now-playing song title and artist"),
            [currentItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle],
            NSLocalizedString (@"by", @"Article between song name and artist name"),
            [currentItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]]];

    if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped) {

        [nowPlayingLabel setText: [
                NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",
                NSLocalizedString (@"Music-ended Instructions", @"Label for prompting user to play music again after it has stopped")]];

    }
}


- (void) handle_PlaybackStateChanged: (id) notification {

    MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = [musicPlayer playbackState];

    if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused) {

        navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = playBarButton;

    } else if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {

        navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = pauseBarButton;

    } else if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped) {

        navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = playBarButton;

        // Even though stopped, invoking 'stop' ensures that the music player will play  
        //      its queue from the start.
        [musicPlayer stop];

    }
}

- (void) handle_iPodLibraryChanged: (id) notification {
]
}



#pragma mark Application playback control_________________

- (IBAction) playAppSound: (id) sender {

    [appSoundPlayer play];
    playing = YES;
    [appSoundButton setEnabled: NO];
}

- (void) alertView: routeChangeAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex: buttonIndex {

    if ((NSInteger) buttonIndex == 1) {
        [appSoundPlayer play];
    } else {
        [appSoundPlayer setCurrentTime: 0];
        [appSoundButton setEnabled: YES];
    }

    [routeChangeAlertView release];         
}



#pragma mark AV Foundation delegate methods____________

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) appSoundPlayer successfully: (BOOL) flag {

    playing = NO;
    [appSoundButton setEnabled: YES];
}

- (void) audioPlayerBeginInterruption: player {

    NSLog (@"Interrupted. The system has paused audio playback.");

    if (playing) {

        playing = NO;
        interruptedOnPlayback = YES;
    }
}

- (void) audioPlayerEndInterruption: player {

    NSLog (@"Interruption ended. Resuming audio playback.");

        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    if (interruptedOnPlayback) {

        [appSoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [appSoundPlayer play];
        playing = YES;
        interruptedOnPlayback = NO;
    }
}



#pragma mark Table view delegate methods

- (void) musicTableViewControllerDidFinish: (MusicTableViewController *) controller {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [self restorePlaybackState];
}



#pragma mark Application setup

- (void) setupApplicationAudio {

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]    pathForResource:    @"sound"
                                                        ofType:             @"caf"];

    NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
    self.soundFileURL = newURL;
    [newURL release];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];

   // [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];

    UInt32 doSetProperty = 0;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (
        kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
        sizeof (doSetProperty),
        &doSetProperty
                             );


    // Registers the audio route change listener callback function
    AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (
        kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,
        audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,
        self
    );

    // Activates the audio session.

    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];

    // Instantiates the AVAudioPlayer object, initializing it with the sound
    AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: soundFileURL error: nil];
    self.appSoundPlayer = newPlayer;
    [newPlayer release];

    [appSoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [appSoundPlayer setVolume: 1.0];
    [appSoundPlayer setDelegate: self];
}


- (void) registerForMediaPlayerNotifications {

    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [notificationCenter addObserver: self
                           selector: @selector (handle_NowPlayingItemChanged:)
                               name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                             object: musicPlayer];

    [notificationCenter addObserver: self
                           selector: @selector (handle_PlaybackStateChanged:)
                               name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                             object: musicPlayer];


    [musicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
}



- (BOOL) useiPodPlayer {

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: PLAYER_TYPE_PREF_KEY]) {
        return YES;     
    } else {
        return NO;
    }       
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];   
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}


- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {
    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
        switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                [self togglePlayPause];
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
                [self playAudio];
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
                [self pauseAudio];
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }
}

- (IBAction) playOrPauseMusic: (id)sender {

    [self togglePlayPause];

}


- (void)playAudio {

    [musicPlayer play];
}

- (void)pauseAudio {
    [musicPlayer pause];
}

- (void)togglePlayPause {


    MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = [musicPlayer playbackState];

    if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped || playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused) {
        [musicPlayer play];
    } else if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
        [musicPlayer pause];
    }
}



// Configure the application.
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];



    [self setupApplicationAudio];

    [self setPlayedMusicOnce: NO];

    [self setNoArtworkImage:    [UIImage imageNamed: @"no_artwork.png"]];       

    [self setPlayBarButton:     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay
                                                                                 target: self
                                                                                 action: @selector (playOrPauseMusic:)]];

    [self setPauseBarButton:    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemPause
                                                                                 target: self
                                                                                 action: @selector (playOrPauseMusic:)]];

    [addOrShowMusicButton   setTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"Add Music", @"Title for 'Add Music' button, before user has chosen some music")
                            forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    [appSoundButton         setTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"Play App Sound", @"Title for 'Play App Sound' button")
                            forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    [nowPlayingLabel setText: NSLocalizedString (@"Instructions", @"Brief instructions to user, shown at launch")];


    if ([self useiPodPlayer]) {

        [self setMusicPlayer: [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]];

        if ([musicPlayer nowPlayingItem]) {


            navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;

            [self handle_NowPlayingItemChanged: nil];


            if ([musicPlayer playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused) {
                navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = playBarButton;
            }
        }

    } else {

        [self setMusicPlayer: [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]];

        [musicPlayer setShuffleMode: MPMusicShuffleModeOff];
        [musicPlayer setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeNone];
    }   

    [self registerForMediaPlayerNotifications];


    [self setBackgroundColorTimer: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3.5
                                                                    target: self
                                                                  selector: @selector (updateBackgroundColor)
                                                                  userInfo: nil
                                                                   repeats: YES]];
}

// Invoked by the backgroundColorTimer.
- (void) updateBackgroundColor {

    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 3.0];

    CGFloat redLevel    = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat greenLevel  = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat blueLevel   = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: redLevel
                                                green: greenLevel
                                                 blue: blueLevel
                                                alpha: 1.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

#pragma mark Application state management_____________

- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void) viewDidUnload {


    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                                                  object: musicPlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                                  object: musicPlayer];

    [musicPlayer endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
    [musicPlayer                release];

    [artworkItem                release]; 
    [backgroundColorTimer       invalidate];
    [backgroundColorTimer       release];
    [navigationBar              release];
    [noArtworkImage             release];
    [nowPlayingLabel            release];
    [pauseBarButton             release];
    [playBarButton              release];
    [soundFileURL               release];
    [userMediaItemCollection    release];

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: AVPlayer has no problem accessing iPod library.

Comment: can you help me out how to access it , ..can u edit it in the program which i have posted it would be a big help .

Comment: i am fetching music from MusicLibraryViewController it displays music in a tableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These four lines should get you started :)

```
MPMediaItem *nowPlayingItem = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;

NSURL * mediaURL = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

AVPlayerItem * myAVPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:mediaURL];

AVPlayer * myAvPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:myAVPlayerItem];
```

Comment: this will be added in viewDidload if i am correct , i wanted to know how to access remote Events since i have used musicPlayer which is MPMusicPlayerController object in remoteEvents Method () 

should i change it to avplayer or since now musicPlayer is being played in avPlayer or it doesnt matter

can i contact u via email

Comment: For the sake of anyone else who goes here to learn, you should keep it here, any solutions found via e-mail won't help the rest of the community. So here's what I wrote you via e-mail:
Create an AVPlayer:
AVPlayer * myAVPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
and then use above code to insert a mpmediaitem into it.

Comment: Well first of all, the audio queue stuff isn't really important, all that is handled automatically by the avplayer. So you really just need the five lines... and then it works...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have the time to rewrite your entire project :) - I would just restart from scratch and use the five lines I've given you, they are enough to get your AVPlayer playing. :)

Comment: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL always returns null for me. How does this work for you?

Comment: having the same issue as @random